# Sensu check return critical but but uchiwa show green

Tags: sensu

I have http check on sensu , sensu client return critical but uchiwa show check as green .

```
check : 
"request1":{
"command": "/etc/sensu/plugins/check-http.rb -U XXX -a XXXX -t 5 -q 'OK' -u  http://XXXX:8081/helix/v1/unititems/?lang=en&fq=%28seller_ipro_id_ext_ref%3A5139391%29&limit=1",
      "interval": 60,
      "occurrences": 1,
      "refresh": 60 ,
      "subscribers": ["helix_check"],
      "handlers": [  "NOC","slack" ]
},
```

output in of uchiwa web application :

[image]

Comment: Sound like more of a bug in uchiwa and that should be reported in uchiwa git: https://github.com/sensu/uchiwa. Could you also post the result from the check? Is the return code 2?

Comment: Yes , return code is 2 ..